# Consultar varios campos desde un solo input por php

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, formularios, input

Hola soy nueva en esto de la programación y estoy intentando hacer un registro y control de asistencia a un evento, ya tengo el espacio de registro donde un estudiante se registra con sus 3 invitados, la manera de identificarlos es por sus documentos de identidad, los registros llegan a la tabla.

El problema es cuando en otro espacio hago una consulta para controlar el acceso al evento, en esta consulta se utiliza el documento de identidad para mostrar los datos del estudiante y sus invitados, si se digita el documento del estudiante aparece su nombre, el nombre de sus 3 invitados y sus documentos de identidad pero esto debe pasar también con los documentos de sus invitados, al ingresarlos debe dar la misma información.

Paso a explicar un poco mi código antes de mostrarlo, los doc son los documentos de identidad, la idea es que si se digita cualquier documento en ese input se pueda traer todo el registro del estudiantes y sus invitados. Ya intente agregando un OR al WHERE pero solo me trae el registro que corresponda al name del input, en este caso me trae el doc_est1 que sería el documento del estudiante pero no me traería nada si digito el documento de alguno de sus invitados a menos de que se cambie el name de ese input. Por eso mi pregunta:

Hay alguna manera de ubicar en el input todos los campos y usar en el php un or para que se púeda realizar la consulta desde cualquier documento de identidad de ese registro? o hay alguna otra manera de realizar esta consulta sin necesidad de hacer vistas en las base de datos? (esto ya lo probe y funciona pero luego tengo que agregar un control de acceso con checks pero que al apuntar a una vista me complica la actualización del estado de acceso)

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento funcionando:

```
<form id="verified-form" method="POST" action="consulta.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id="doc-est-consul" for="doc_est">Documento de identidad</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="doc_est1"
        id="doc-est-verified"
        class="form-control consulta-doc"
        placeholder="Documento de identidad"
        required
        >
   </div>
  <div>
    <button
            type="submit"
            id="submit-consul"
            class="submit-button"
            name="consulta_btn"
            >Consultar
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<div>

 <div id="resultados">  
   <?php
   include("db.php");
   
   if(isset($_POST['consulta_btn']))

   {
       $doc_est1 = $_POST['doc_est1'];
       $existe=0;

       //echo"Presiono el boton Consultar";
       
       $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $tabla_db2 WHERE doc_est1 = '$doc_est1'");
       while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
      {
          echo"<form id='ing_check' method='POST' action='consulta.php'>";
          echo"<h2>Graduando e invitados</h2>";
          echo "<table class>";
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td> " . $consulta['nm_est']."&nbsp;"; echo $consulta['apd_est']."</td>";
          echo "<td> " . $consulta['pgm_est']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $consulta['ing_est']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>
      <input class='checkbox' type='checkbox' name='ing_est[]' value='ing_est' class='checkbox-ing'>
           </td>";  
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td> " . $consulta['nm_inv1']."&nbsp;"; echo $consulta['apd_inv1'] ."</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $consulta['doc_inv1']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $consulta['ing_inv1']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>
      <input class='checkbox' type='checkbox' name='ing_est[]' value='ing_est' class='checkbox-ing'>
           </td>"; 
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td> " . $consulta['nm_inv2']."&nbsp;"; echo $consulta['apd_inv2'] ."</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $consulta['doc_inv2']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $consulta['ing_inv2']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>
      <input class='checkbox' type='checkbox' name='ing_est[]' value='ing_est' class='checkbox-ing'>
           </td>"; 
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td> " . $consulta['nm_inv3']."&nbsp;"; echo $consulta['apd_inv3'] ."</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $consulta['doc_inv3']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $consulta['ing_inv3']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>
      <input class='checkbox' type='checkbox' name='ing_est[]' value='ing_est' class='checkbox-ing'>
           </td>"; 
          echo "</tr>";
          
          echo "</table>";
     echo "<div>
```

Agradezco su ayuda hasta ahora estoy empezando en todo esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema esta en tu consulta mysql, según tu consulta te mostrara los resultados siempre y cuando en el **input** escribas una cadena que sea igual a tu campo **doc_est1**, por ende, si escribes el nombre de su papa, nunca encontrara un resultado con ese nombre, ya que  el nombre de los invitados esta en otro campo, ejemplo **doc_inv1, doc_inv2 y doc_inv3 en la BD**. Tienes que hacer referencia a los campos en donde quieres hacer la comprobación, ejemplo:

**SELECT * FROM $tabla_db2 WHERE doc_est1 = '$doc_est1' OR doc_inv1 = '$doc_est1' OR doc_inv2 = '$doc_est1' OR doc_inv3 = '$doc_est1';**

Me dices si te funciono, suerte.

Comment: Funciono funciono, perfecto muchísimas gracias ya con esto me queda más claro la lógica del select pensé que el inconveniente lo tenia en el input pero me queda claro que es al momento de hacer la consulta muchassss graciassssss